# Is there a publicly available informer tagger or dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language-processing

I am working on a question answering system. I've learned that informer spans are valuable features for question classification. However from what I've read I wasn't able to find any publicly available dataset for this task, or a trained tagger. Is there any? People seem to just hand-label their dataset.

If there aren't any available, then how does one label the dataset and build the tagger?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Questions about tools and libraries are off-topic, here, but I guess the question is still fine if the answer to that part is "No, there aren't any." :-) Let's see what happens.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41066014/781723, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/67164/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: @D.W.: the cross-post on SO is now gone.